# Snowflake Kafka connector doubts and questions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-connect

I am using 3 server cluster for the Kafka Configuration, with Snowflake connector REST API to push the data to Snowflake database: All are 3 different VMs running on AWS

1.In this, does we require 3 kafka individual server zookeeper-services needs to be up and running in cluster else only 1 is enough, as if it needs to be executed in all the 3 servers zookeeper services, does it require different port configurations like for ex:

1.a:**zookeeper.connect=xx.xx.xx.xxx:2181, xx.xx.xx.xxx:2182, xx.xx.xx.xxx:2183** else it should be 2181 in all the servers.properties file

1.b:**PLAINTEXT://localhost:9091 in server1, PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 and PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093** (Even in this it should be localhost else IP Address) that needs to be given?

1.c:**server.1=<zookeeper_1_IP>:2888:3888, server.1=<zookeeper_2_IP>:2888:3888, server.1=<zookeeper_3_IP>:2888:3888** (Over here on each server the 2888:3888 needs to be same right?)

1.d:**Clientport=2181** needs to be the same across the services in all 3 VMs else it needs to be different?

1.e:Does the listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092 on each server should have separate **port** like
VM-Server1:9092, VM-Server2:9093, VM-Server3:9094. Else the master server-IP should be given in the worker-nodes that is Server2 and Server3 else the own server IP of that worker-node

2. What should be the configuration for connector in regards with **REST-API** for the configuration item **"tasks.max":"1"**. As I am going with 3 server cluster for Kafka and would be starting the 3 **distribute-connector** on all the 3 machines
3. I am getting duplicates, if I am starting the services of distributed connector in the 2nd server, how these duplicate records can be avoided. But yes if its only 1 distributed-connector is running the services, then there are no duplicates. Please advice, as the lag gets increased if only 1 distributed-connector services is up and running.
4. Create /data/zookeeper/myid file and give value 1 for zookeeper1 , 2 for zookeeper2 and 3for zookeeper3. Is this necessary when you are in different VM?
5. The distributed-connector services once started executing for sometime and then it gets disconnected
6. Any other parameter for the 3 server cluster architecture and best practices which needs to be followed

Answer (score 0):

### Kafka and Zookeeper

You only need one Kafka broker and Zookeeper server, although having more would provide fault tolerance. You don't need to manually create anything in Zookeeper such as `myid` files.

The ports don't need to be the same, but it is obviously easier to draw a network diagram and automate the configuration if they are.

Regarding Kafka listeners, read [this post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/). For Zookeeper, follow its documentation if you want to create a cluster.

Or use Amazon MSK / Confluent Cloud, etc. instead of EC2, and this is all done for you.

---

### Kafka Connect

`tasks.max` can be as much as you want, but if you have a **source** connector, then multiple threads will probably cause duplicates, yes.

Comment: Do you mean to say in virtual machines, the port needs to be different right? for each individual vm-server.

Comment: And how can we restrict duplicates as its even in the single server as well as the cluster environment. Please guide. As I am getting duplicates even in the single as well as dual node cluster. As the partition of the data consumption is 5. So these 5 partitions are being used to pump the data. If as you said above if we take only tasks.max=1 then how the parallelism can be achieved and the throughput performance will be achieved. Please help

Comment: The ports can be the same for each unique machine. The only reason to make them different is if you run multiple Kafka processes or Zookepeer servers on the same machine. I have never used this connector, so I have no advice on duplicates, but if there is only one task, then there is only one process pulling data from Snowflake and writing to Kafka. If there is something that tracks "progress" in the connector (via primary keys, or timestamps, or some other property in the database), then there shouldn't be duplicates.

Comment: For future issues, I suggest you file a ticket on their forums, or make an issue here https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-kafka-connector/issues